# How to use bslib theme with shinywidgets actionBttn

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets, bslib

I am using a theme with custom colors for primary, secondary, etc. but when I set the color option to primary, the actionBttn() does not recognize my theme color. How do I change the actionBttn color to match my theme?

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- page_sidebar(
  title = "My dashboard",
  theme = bs_theme(primary = "purple"),
  sidebar = sidebar("Sidebar",
  actionBttn("go", "Go", color = "primary")),
  "Main"
)

shinyApp(ui, function(input, output) {})
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your action button? For starters, it is not tied to any server side event that would have a side-effect on your UI. You could bind an observer to your action button that uses `bs_theme_update()`.

Comment: I am using bslib to create a dashboard, and the colors that I am using are different from the defaults, and I just need to change the default actionBttn color from blue to match what my colors are in my dashboard theme

Comment: It works fine for me. Please update your library.